# changing font size of first letter of each word with javascript append issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have this js that is adjusting the size of the first letter of each word in my headers. The only prob is that it appends all the results to each header. So each header on the page, becomes a combo of every header on the page. This jsfiddle link makes what Im saying much more clear:

http://jsfiddle.net/GKYuG/

Can someone please let me know how I can get the correct result?

Comment: please show your code here. we don't like going to another page to find your code, and when someone comes here in the future to see the question, that link may no longer be working

Comment: @DOK: I would almost rather go to a jsFiddle than have code posted here (though both is best I suppose) - then I know they took the time to set up a test case that shows their issue.

Comment: @josh.trow The problem is, that SO loses value if a question/answer is void due to some other site being unavailable. jsfiddle is nice, but the code in question should be posted here first. Also posting the code, properly formated here, shows effort too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var titles = new Array();
    titles[0] = 'latest_news';
    titles[1] = 'contact_me';

    $('.title').each(function(){
        var words = $(this).text().split(' '); 
        var html = ''; 
        $.each(words, function() { 
            html += '<span style="font-size:200%">'+this.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+this.substring(1) + ' '; 
        }); 
        $(this).html(html); 
    });

});
```

You have to iterate through the selected divs, otherwise you are applying your changes to all the divs selected by the selector.

Comment: I don't think you need both `$(document).ready` functions ..Just one :)

Comment: lol, of course, you're right. i didn't look at that part of the code :)

Comment: thanks Andre! That did it. And sorry for the poorly jsfiddled code everyone.